# Why I am getting illegal pattern on pattern matching?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

```
1> X = 10.
10
2> Y = 9.
9
3> X - 1 = Y.
* 1: illegal pattern
4> Y = X - 1.
9
5> 10 - 1 = Y.
9
```

Can you explain to me what illegal pattern in query `3>` is? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The variable that you are binding to needs to be on the left side, not the right.

This is the correct expression:

```
Y = X - 1.
```

Comment: Expression 5 is correct because it is a pattern match. With that line, you're saying "I want Y (which is 9) to be matched against 10 - 1 (which is 9)". Binding variables is just a special case of pattern matching, in expression 2 , you're saying "I want 9 to be matched against Y (which is unbound)." Since it is unbound, it can match anything and it is then bound to the variable from that point on.

Comment: How about "I want Y (which is 9) to be matched against X - 1 (which is 9) in exp 3?

Comment: In 5 the shell is helping you a bit as it can see that the "pattern" can be evaluated so it does it and then checks that the result is a pattern. Which it is ``10``. In 3 this is not possible as there is no way that ``X-1`` can be interpreted as a patten, it is an expression. You can say that a pattern is something which describes what the structure of the data looks like and ``X-1`` does not do that. The handling of the shell in 5 is a bit confusing and probably shouldn't be done.